# Need thread management when one thread is taking too much CPU power

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an application that distributes work to multiple threads. Sometimes one thread takes too much CPU load and all other threads suffer of that. What can I do to manage threads in such way that if one thread is going up with using CPU then just pause it, or slice it down to   make all threads load to be more or less even.

**Updated** My tasks are independent. Not sure if is possible to add performance counters for each thread and measure load. If thread goes out of limits than pause it until later time.

**Updated** Problem with using TPL load balancing is that my threads are STA. Kind of solution is to create home brewed load balancing following well known algorithms like "round-robin load balancing".

Comment: This question is so broad that it's impossible to give a reasonable answer. The answer depends on what kind of work the threads are doing, how many threads and CPU cores you have, whether some threads are more important than others, etc. Without more information about your particular situation, you're not going to get very good answers.

Comment: Agree, that it could be a try to get simple answer for a complex problem. Just stamble upon on load balancing that has been advertised in TPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that *you* distribute work to multiple threads. So, it's up to *you* to break down and distribute the work properly. You will need to understand the performance of your code well enough tht you can look at the workload and decide how much resources that workload will require. You can then split up the workload so that each unit of work is more or less the same in terms of resources.

I don't think you're going to find a complete magical solution. Something like the Task Parallel Library i .NET 4.0 and above can help, but it's not a silver bullet.

Comment: Valid point, but unfortunately, I don't have such info that allows me to estimate the load

Comment: Then I think you're SOL, at least in general. For instance, it's not always a good idea to just pause one task. Other tasks might be dependent on the successful completion of that task.

Comment: Is it important that all the work gets done, or is it important that each task gets some work done? Keep in mind that it might be better for the high-load task to finish its work and get out of the way of the normal tasks.

Comment: It is more important all work to be done, i have 100 work items and run only 10 threads approximately. For me is better to show 9 threads working than show all not working because of one heavy loaded.

Comment: Long story short, I strongly suggest you look at the `Task` class in .NET 4.0 and the `async` / `await` keywords in .NET 4.5/C# 5.0. They will help you manage the number of threads independently of the number of _tasks_ that need to be performed. They will also optimize based on the computer the code is running on.